# Find the recurrence relation for string length $n$ formed from the elements of the set {x, y, z, t} that do not contain $xx ,yy ,zz, tt$ $(n \geq5)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

So here's what i've got so far: 
Let $a_n$ denote the number of string n length formed from the elements of the set {$x, y, z, t$} that do not contain $ xx ,yy ,zz, tt $
There are 12 possible way of dividing this string:

- $ xy,xz,xt + a_{n-2}$
- $ yx,yz,yt + a_{n-2}$
- $ zx,zy,zt + a_{n-2}$
- $ tx,tz,tz + a_{n-2}$
  **So the recurrence relation i got is:**
  $a_n = 12a_{n-2}$  $(n \geq 5)$
  with the initial condition  is $a_3 = 36$
  Im having trouble verifying this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not correct.  You cannot prepend $xy$ onto a string of length $n-2$ if the string starts with $y$.  A better approach is to just extend the string by $1$ because you always have the same number of choices for the extension.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124964/discussion-on-answer-by-ross-millikan-find-the-recurrence-relation-for-string-le).